# python 3.5.3のimportエラーについて

Tags: python

以下のmain_nunchuck.pyを実行しました。`sudo python3 main_nunchuck.py`

```
from ..import_directory.Nunchuck.RaspberryPi import nunchuck
from ..import_directory.python_sdk.milkcocoa import milkcocoa
```

すると、以下のエラーが発生しました。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "main_nunchuck.py", line 1,in <module>
      from ..import_directory.Nunchuck.RaspberryPi import nunchuck
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

ファイル構造は以下の様にしています。

```
└─/pi
   └─/nunchuck_control
       │  main_nunchuck.py
       │
       └─/import_directory
           │ 
           │
           ├─/Nunchuck
           │     |
           │     |__/RaspberryPi
           │            nunchuck.py
           |
           ├─/python_sdk
                 |
                 |
                 ├─/milkcocoa
                 |     |   milkcocoa.py
                       |   __int__.py
                       |
                       ├─/paho
                           |
                           ├─/mqtt
```

どのようにしてpythonのimportをすれば良いのでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

========追伸1==========
 `__int__.py`を以下のように各フォルダに挿入しました。

```
└─/pi
   └─/nunchuck_control
       │  main_nunchuck.py
       │
       └─/import_directory
           │ __int__.py
           │
           ├─/Nunchuck
           │     |  __int__.py
           |     |
           │     ├─/RaspberryPi
           |     |     __int__.py
           │           nunchuck.py
           |
           ├─/python_sdk
                 |   __int__.py
                 |
                 ├─/milkcocoa
                 |     |   milkcocoa.py
                       |   __int__.py
                       |
                       ├─/paho
                           |  __int__.py
                           |
                           ├─/mqtt
                           |    __int__.py
                                client.py
```

そして、`main_nunchuck.py`を実行しました。

```
from import_directory.Nunchuck.RaspberryPi import nunchuck
from import_directory.python_sdk.milkcocoa import milkcocoa as milkcocoa
```

mtb_beta様にお答え頂いたように`nunchuck.py`のimport errorは発生しませんでした。ありがとうございます。ただ、`client.py`のimport errorが発生しました。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "main_nunchuck.py", line 2,in <module>
      from import_directory.python_sdk.milkcocoa import milkcocoa as milkcocoa
　　File "/home/pi/nunchuck_control/import_directory/python_sdk/milkcocoa/milkcocoa.py", line 6, in <module>
   　 from paho.mqtt import client as mqtt
ImportError:No module named 'paho'
```

と表示されました。度々、すみません。協力頂ければ幸いです。

=====追伸2======
自己解決しました。`milkcocoa.py`の6行目を以下のように変更するとうまく行きました。

```
from import_directory.python_sdk.milkcocoa.paho.mqtt import client as mqtt
```

理由は分かりませんが、なんとなく絶対PATHを入力するとうまく動きました。なぜ、相対PATHではうまくいかず、絶対PATHではうまく動くのでしょうか?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

まず、Pythonではパッケージとなるディレクトリには `__init__.py` が必要です。
[こちら](https://docs.python.jp/3/reference/import.html?highlight=%E3%83%91%E3%83%83%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8#regular-packages)が公式ドキュメントです。

次のようなファイルは必要かと思いますので用意しましょう。 `__init__.py` はファイルがあれば良いので、中身は空で大丈夫です。

`import_directory/__init__.py`
`import_directory/Nunchuck/__init__.py`
`import_directory/Nunchuck/RaspberryPi/__init__.py`
`python_sdk/__init__.py`
`python_sdk/milkcocoa/__init__.py`

次にimportの行ですが、先頭の `..` は不要のように見えます。以下のように修正して一度試してみてください。

```
from import_directory.Nunchuck.RaspberryPi import nunchuck
from import_directory.python_sdk.milkcocoa import milkcocoa
```

Comment: `__int__.py` を各フォルダーに入れていませんでした。明日、 `__int__.py` の空ファイルをフォルダーを挿入します。